# How it adjust the max width of a textbox in a TreeViewItem to the edges of the container

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

The text box in the follow TreeViewItem, constructed by a data template, is not horizontal adjustable to the edges of the tree view.

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="PageTemplate" x:DataType="local:OnenoteEntity">
        <TreeViewItem AutomationProperties.Name="{x:Bind Page.Title}" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch">
            <StackPanel
                MaxWidth="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=UiOnenoteTreeView}"
                HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                VerticalAlignment="Top"
                Orientation="Horizontal">

                <Image
                    Height="{Binding ActualHeight, ElementName=UiNameOnenoteEntity, Mode=OneWay}"
                    Margin="0,0,10,0"
                    VerticalAlignment="Center"
                    Source="Resources/Page.png" />

                <TextBlock
                    x:Name="UiNameOnenoteEntity"
                    HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                    VerticalAlignment="Center"
                    Style="{ThemeResource BodyTextBlockStyle}"
                    Text="{x:Bind Page.Title}"
                    TextWrapping="WrapWholeWords" />
            </StackPanel>
        </TreeViewItem>
    </DataTemplate>
```

The text in the box dont wrapp at the edge of the container in the tree view. The text box has the width size of the actual text, according to the following picture:

[Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dIvsC.png)

What can i do, to wrap the text? Thanks for answering

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @2zemec said, you need to change the TextWrapping property of TetxBlock to **Wrap**. In addition, since you set the Orientation of StackPanel as **Horizontal**, the StackPanel will give the full width to each child control, and then put them out horizontally. It will not limit the width of TextBlock, so the TextBlock won't wrap. In this case, you can also set a **MaxWidth** for TextBlock to limit it or use **Grid** to replace the StackPanel. For example:

```
<Grid MaxWidth="300">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Image Height="{Binding ActualHeight, ElementName=UiNameOnenoteEntity, Mode=OneWay}"
           Margin="0,0,10,0"
           VerticalAlignment="Center"
           Source="Assets/StoreLogo.png" />
    <TextBlock Grid.Column="1"
               x:Name="UiNameOnenoteEntity"
               HorizontalAlignment="Left"
               VerticalAlignment="Center"
               Text="{x:Bind Title}"
               TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Thanks al lot Faywang and @2zemec

Answer (score 0):

Try to change `TextWrapping="WrapWholeWords"`  to `TextWrapping="Wrap"`. According to [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.textwrapping?view=netframework-4.8)

> Wrap - Line-breaking occurs if the line overflows beyond the available block width, even if the standard line breaking algorithm cannot determine any line break opportunity, as in the case of a very long word constrained in a fixed-width container with no scrolling allowed.